# Centos locate file in binary file

Tags: centos, grep

I have ran a command to find a string in files on the server like this:

```
cd /
grep -r "string to be found" *
```

And the server returned some results like this

```
Binary file dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:10.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 matches
Binary file dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:10.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 matches
```

As far as I know these are files that keep the actual storage on the raid matrix (please correct me if I am wrong). How can I find exactly where my match is located?

Is there any faster solution to this than running "grep" all accross the files of the server?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Generally on a binary file you have to do something like:

```
$ string /binary/file | grep -i whatuwant
```

but if u want search on text file, my advice is:

```
$ find / -type f -exec grep -i whatuwant '{}' ';'
```

Comment: Actually what I want is to find a script that performs a bruteforce attack on some domain. The string that I am searching for is the domainname itself. So if there are any matches it means that there is a particular script doing so

Comment: Is the script active?

Comment: yes because i receive from time to time notifications like this one http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=84vJ6eWv from time to time